# How do I make a doorway going into the next scene?

Tags: scene, gdevelop

I new to [GDevelop](https://gdevelop-app.com/) and I use it on a Chromebook.

I'm making this game that I'm kind of proud of! I've found a way to teleport players to the next scene, by just putting the condition, then just make the event: Open url (and then the link of the scene I want the player to travel to). When I use the method I am using now, The game keeps opening tabs of different scenes! And, when I try going back to a tab, It creates like, eight new tabs! It is probably just a glitch. I go to the events section then I set the action to be: open url or file: And then the link of the next scene. I would just like to find a better way.

Can I get a javascript code to make the player teleport when it touches the door or the teleporter?

I would really like to find a BETTER way to teleport the player.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what the problem is. `gdevelop` doesn't appear to be a commonly used tag, so assume none of us know it (but we're quick studies). Now explain your problem again... What exactly did you do? How can we recreate it? Can you show an example? Is there a specific function/config/setup/??? that  you're using to open a link?

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple (unless the game is supposed to open a new link, if so please specify).

You can just use the collision condition for when the player is in collision with a door and use the change the scene action to change the scene to the next scene.

[image: example:]